# Incompatibilidad entre Angular 8 y reCaptcha ¿Hay algun ReCaptcha compatible con Angular 8?

Tags: angular, angular8, captcha, recaptcha

Buenas y gracias de antemano a todo aquel/aquella que conteste a mi duda.

Soy desarrollador Jr. de front y mis conocimientos son bastante escasos.

Estoy intentando implementar un ReCaptcha en Angular 8, pero por lo que me ha dicho un compañero, son incompatibles. Y por eso, al intentar instalarlo con `npm install ng-recaptcha --save` en el proyecto me da error:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree     
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: mac-internacional@0.0.0       
npm ERR! Found: zone.js@0.10.3
npm ERR! node_modules/zone.js
npm ERR!   zone.js@"~0.10.2" from the root project      
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer zone.js@"~0.9.1" from @angular/core@8.2.14
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/core
npm ERR!   @angular/core@"~8.2.5" from the root project 
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

¿Alguien sabe si hay alguna versión compatible con Angular 8?
Gracias de nuevo.
Un saludo.

Comment: No veo en su repositorio ningún problema reportado de compatibilidad, de hecho las últimas actualizaciones dicen ser compatibles hasta con Angular 12: https://github.com/DethAriel/ng-recaptcha/releases/tag/v5.0.0 y https://github.com/DethAriel/ng-recaptcha/releases/tag/v8.0.0

Comment: Jo, pues no se instala y no se porqué :(

Comment: No sé si has jugado con las versiones de Angular, pero dice que tienes zone 0.10.2 pero está buscando 0.9.1 para angular 8

Comment: Si solo ejecutas `npm install ng-recaptcha` te va agregar la versión más reciente de la biblioteca que sería la 8.0.0 y esa no es compatible con Angular 8. Ve al repositorio https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-recaptcha y selecciona la pestaña `Versions` ahí verás la lista de versiones anteriores, para Angular 8 podrías probar la 5.0.0

Comment: Tampoco funcionan otras versiones. Y respondiendo a Pablo, ya intentamos cambiar zone a 0.9.1, pero tampoco ha funcionado.